# Sql Count rows which contains some value

Tags: mysql, sql

Now I want to count the rows where column contains a value or not null. I am the beginner of SQL; my SQL query is as below:

```
select count(news) AS news_count, count(`msg`) as msg_count , count('req') as req_count 
from news_msg_activity 
where news!='' 
UNION 
select count(news) AS news_count, count(`msg`) as msg_count , count('req') as req_count 
from news_msg_activity 
where msg!='' 
UNION  
select count(news) AS news_count, count(`msg`) as msg_count , count('req') as req_count  
from news_msg_activity 
where req!=''
```

When I run the query it give two numbers in outcome. But I need a single number result where it will count the number of records from the above operation. I don't know how to write that query. Can anybody help me?

but I need like

```
news_count || msg_count || req_count                          
    2      ||     2     ||    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your query in a subquery.

```
SELECT * -- here you can sum, count or whatever elese you need
FROM (
  -- your query goes here
) as src
```

Or simply

```
select 
    sum(news!='') AS news_count
    , sum( msg!='' ) as msg_count 
    , sum(req!='') as req_count 
from news_msg_activity
```

as boolean statement evaluate to integers as 0/1 (false/true) - this acts as a count where the condition is met.

check the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c780/1

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT(column)` will already return the number of non-null records, so unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, you can make this much simpler. The following query should return the number of non-null records for each field:

```
select count(news) AS news_count
, count(`msg`) as msg_count
, count(req) as req_count 
from news_msg_activity
```

If your concern is eliminating empty strings from the count, you can use the `NULLIF` function:

```
select count(nullif(news, '')) AS news_count
, count(nullif(`msg`, '')) as msg_count
, count(nullif(req, '')) as req_count 
from news_msg_activity
```

Comment: last column   count('req') as req_count   not working.. it count all the rows

Comment: Oh, right, sorry. I just copied your syntax without thinking about it, but you can't use single-quotes to escape a field name. It's just being interpreted as a constant. Try my edited version.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you really need UNION? Maybe something like that?

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        count(news) AS news_count
    FROM
        news_msg_activity 
    WHERE
        news!= '') a,
    (SELECT 
        count(msg) as msg_count
    FROM
        news_msg_activity 
    WHERE
        msg!= '') b,
    (SELECT 
        count(req) as req_count
    FROM
        news_msg_activity 
    WHERE
        req!= '') c
```

Additionally, make fields `news, msg, req` - NOT NULL in table's scheme. Because now count() counts rows with field's null's values. You may add `IS NOT NULL` to query, but better solution is to make NOT NULL in table's scheme with setting default value. This will save you from "bugs" in future.